# Варианты обособления

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте.

**По-видимому, всемогущий, Магус легко победил Дума и уничтожил Квазара.**

Правильно ли "всемогущий" здесь обособляется запятыми?
Возможен ли другой знак после или перед "всемогущий"?
Интуитивно кажется,что запятая сильно отделяет части предложения по смысловой нагрузке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Всемогущий" - это обособленное определение (будучи всемогущим).

А правило я нашла об обособленных оборотах (мне кажется, подходит и к одиночному определению), такое:

[Если вводное слово стоит в начале или в конце обособленного оборота](http://rustest.edu.ru/rules/punktuazia/obosobl/3274/) (обособления, уточнения, пояснения, присоединения), то никаким знаком от оборота оно не отделяется.

---

> [Вводные слова не отделяются от обособленного оборота](http://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/726-210_vvodnye_slova__slovosochetaniya_i_predlozheniya.html),
>
> если даже находятся в самом начале или самом конце предложения:
>
> *По-видимому опасаясь снежных заносов, руководитель группы отменил восхождение на вершину горы; Оставьте вы эти новые доводы,
> неубедительные и надуманные конечно.*

Если это правило "наше" (то есть если я правильно сочла причастие "всемогущий" обособленным определением и с ним можно обращаться как с оборотом), то не нужна первая запятая.

***По-видимому всемогущий, Магус легко победил Дума и уничтожил Квазара.***

---

Другой знак после определения перед определяемым словом абсолютно невозможен; не тире же?!

Comment: Да,вы правильно поняли смысл предложения. Спасибо за правило.

Comment: При исходном варианте пунктуации ("казнить, нельзя, помиловать") можно только _угадать_ задуманный смысл из двух возможных :)

Answer (score 3):

Здесь не может быть двух запятых. Если смысл в том, что Магус предположительно (или явно) "всемогущ" и потому победил, не должно быть первой запятой. Если же "по-видимому, победил и уничтожил", а могущество не ставится под сомнение, то не должно быть второй.